# woocommerce add variable after price

Tags: plugins

I am kind of new to woocommerce but finding this plugin amazing so far..
I am trying to figure out how to add a variable right after the price which will give the buyer additional information about how many credits he purchased (using stars)

There is an option of adding attributes and showing them as variables but it all shows underneath in the "Additional information" tab and I want that to appear right after the price

the following screenshot better describe what I am looking for:
[image]

***This "stars" additional information must be added to the checkout page as well as sent to the customer as additional important information**

Thanks in advance
Gil

Answer (score 0):

use `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook with priority `15`

```
//test
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','ravs_credits',15);
function ravs_credits(){
    echo'testing';
}
```

above code print `testing` below price on product page.

**Important Link**:

[woocommerce_single_product_summary](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/woocommerce-hooks.php#L128) hook

[WordPress hooks introduction](http://wpcandy.com/teaches/how-to-use-wordpress-hooks/)

---

**Updated**:

I am assuming that your credit range form `1` to `100` and you specify them.now

1. create custom meta box in product post type.read 
   [How To Create Custom Post Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box)
2. read this [technique to create product rating in css](http://stevewamsley.com/technique-to-display-product-ratings-using-css/)

now you get meta box in each product,give it a value between `1` to `100`
now code look like

```
//credits with rating
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','ravs_credits',15);
    function ravs_credits(){
     global $post;
     ?>
     <div class="ravs-credits">
       <p>This package will grant you <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $single); ?> Stars</p>
       <span style="width:<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $single); ?>%" class="rating"></span>
     </div>
     <?php
    }
```

**Important Link**:

1. [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

Comment: Basically it works pretty well thanks. How do I display the attribute instead of echoing a simple text? (testing)

Comment: for that you have to dig in that plugin code and check how it output result in additional information tab.Modify my fuction to achieve desire result.

Comment: which plugin are you using for that info (showing in image)?

Comment: I sm only using Woocommerce plugin.

Comment: I want to ask one thing in what range your credit lies means( 1 to 100 or upper)

Comment: Actually i'm also curious about how you'll give credit to customer, by giving them on the spot discount or define another meta-info for registered customer and store credits after each buy in customer meta-info.

Comment: it's not that complicated as it sounds. I only convert to money to credits so it's easier for the customer in my case to understand. I don't provide discount at all.

Comment: I updated my answer check if it works for you

Comment: Thanks. important question: as I mentioned, this information must appear in the checkout and also be included in the email sent to the user, telling him how many credits he has. is this going to work using your technique?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9126/discussion-between-ravs-and-gil-hamer)